# Capturing ReorderMode for ListView - WP8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I need to know when the ListView comes out of reorder mode. When I long press on the listview, I'm enabling the ReorderMode. After the reordering is done, I press hardware back button and the listview comes out reorder mode. Is there any way to check capture that?

I have tried data binding the ReorderMode property. But it does not capture the ReOrderMode disabled state.

xaml

```
      <ListView x:Name="FolderListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                              SelectionMode="None"
                              IsTapEnabled="True" 
                              Tapped="ListItemTapped" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True"              
                              IsSwipeEnabled="True" Holding="OnItemHold" 
                              ReorderMode="{Binding ReorderMode, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

code-behind

```
    private void OnItemHold(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)//Long Press on ListView
    {
        FolderListView.ReorderMode = ListViewReorderMode.Enabled;
        ReorderModeChanged();
    }        

    public ListViewReorderMode ReorderMode
    {
        get
        {
            return _reorderMode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_reorderMode != value)
            {
                _reorderMode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ReorderMode");
                this.ReorderModeChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReorderModeChanged()
    {
        DBManager dbMan = DBManager.Instance;

        if (this.ReorderMode == ListViewReorderMode.Enabled)
        {
            dbMan.IsReorderEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dbMan.IsReorderEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Any ideas/work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong DataContext for your ListView. You bind some collection to ListView, but this collection does not have ReorderMode property. You can look for binding errors in Output window while debugging your app.